# Case when in Query studio

Tags: query, sql

I am trying to count customer and non-customer in my master-DE. 
Having a customerID means he is an customer.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.customerID is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Customer',
SUM(CASE WHEN a.customerID is empty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Lead',
FROM MasterNewsletter
```

But I am getting that error message "Automation failed due to system error."
When I am adding another field I can see that I don´t get results in both columns. Field "customerID" is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Studio is very useful, but a little unstable. Sometime I try to run a query and I get "Automation failed due to system error.", the I just click **run** again and the query works.

But in your case there is a few adjustments you need to do:

- Remove the last comma (or you will get an error "Field name cannot be blank"
- In the second SUM, change is empty (is empty is not a valid commando) to is null
- Remove single quotes from "as field name"

I reproduced a similar scenario and worked in Query Studio

[image]